# Sending Signals and pselect?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, signals

logic

```
while()
{

  block signal;

  pselect();

  unblock signal;

}
```

While the signals are blocked, can i store the process id that have sent the signal? So that I process them after pselect has done its work and the signals are unblocked?

If there is a better way achieving this can someone guide me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blocked signals are queued and delivered after having been unblocked.

If standard signals (that is no real time signals) are delivered to a process while being blocked **only one instance per standard signal is queued**.

For details please see [`man 7 signal`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html).

---

The process id which sent a signal can be derived if the signal handler had been set up using [`sigaction()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) with  the `sa_flags` member of the passed in `struct sigaction` set to `SA_SIGINFO`.

For details please [see `man sigaction`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html).

Comment: thanks. What if the signals are real time signals? For example a user defined signal? While blocked I sent 3-4 signals? How can I achieve this ?!